# Pyinstaller Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a pyinstaller app distribution

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "folder:folder" --icon=icon.icns MyApp.py
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line
>   30, in  FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory
>   "/Path/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/tcl"
>   not found. [55354] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter

The strange thing is that I'm not using `Tkinter` anywhere in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this in the logs as well:

> 4000 ERROR: Tcl/Tk improperly installed on this system.

And since my app doesn't rely on `Tkinter` anyway, I changed the pyinstaller command to this which fixed the issue:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "folder:folder" --exclude-module tkinter --icon=icon.icns MyApp.py
```

I'm still investigating how to fix my Tcl/Tk installation.